# Why isn't Unity there?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I've installed 11.04 but for some reason Unity isn't there. I'm just getting the old interface.  It's not a graphics card problem as it can run brand new games fine.

Anyone know whats up?

Thanks, Mike.

Comment: Did you install the appropriate driver for your graphics card?

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind. Have you testet out Gnome 3 on the same system prior to upgrading? Gnome 3 will disable Unity. And like @Takkat said, are the drivers for your graphics card working/installed? What kind of session options do you have when you log in?

Comment: Plus, what graphics card do you use?

Comment: Just to make sure you are logging into the right session: log out from the classic session (what you call old interface) and log into an Ubuntu session (see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32447/how-do-i-disable-compiz-in-the-ubuntu-classic-session/34263#34263), but choose *Ubuntu*).

Comment: Did you restart the computer after installation ended?

Comment: Have you upgraded your system from any Ubuntu derivative OS like pinguy?

Answer (score 2):

To check that your hardware supports Unity type in a terminal;

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

If you get a NO response then you will need to install Unity 2D:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Comment: and it would be really nice if you could also tell us where to Unity 2D from, I was of the impression that the 2D version would be released with Ubuntu 11.10