# VLC HD bad playback

Tags: 11.04, video, vlc

I'm getting unsmooth and unsynced vertical playback placback with VLC. My hardware is certainly capable of running 1080p. It's watchable but not as good as on windows with media player classic and the k-lite codec pack. So why is this happening?

Comment: turning off compiz might help, but I'm unsure

Comment: It fixed the framerate, there's still an issue with vertical sync but that's probably to do with VLC. Answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turning off compiz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32447/how-do-i-disable-compiz-in-the-ubuntu-classic-session) and setting VLC's video output to glx fixed the choppy frame rate.

For the vertical sync I turned vertical refresh to 'always on' in ATI catalyst control center.